# Is it a bad practice to have a Cassandra table with partitions of a single row?

Tags: cassandra, primary-key, partition

Let's say I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE request(
  transaction_id text,
  request_date timestamp,
  data text, 
  PRIMARY KEY (transaction_id)
);
```

The transaction_id is unique, so as far as I understand **each partition in this table would have one row only** and I'm not sure if this situation causes a performance issue in the OS, maybe because Cassandra creates a file for each partition causing lots of files to manage for its hosting OS, as a note I'm not sure how Cassandra creates its files for its tables.

In this scenario I can find a request by its transaction_id like

`select data from request where transaction_id = 'abc';`

If the previous assumption is correct, a different approach could be the next one?

```
CREATE TABLE request( 
  the_date date, 
  transaction_id text, 
  request_date timestamp, 
  data text, 
  PRIMARY KEY ((the_date), transaction_id)
);
```

The field *the_date* would change every next day, so the partitions in the table would be created for each day.

In this scenario I would have to have *the_date* data always **available** to the client so I can find a request using the next query

`select data from request where the_date = '2020-09-23' and transaction_id = 'abc';`

Thank you in advance for your kind help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cassandra doesn't create a separate file for each partition. One SSTable file may contain multiple partitions.  Partitions that consist only of one row are often called "skinny rows" - they aren't very bad, but may cause some performance issues:

- to access such partitions you still need to read a block with compressed data (by default it's 64Kb) that needs to be decompressed to read that data. If you're doing really random access, such blocks would be discarded from file cache and needs to be re-read from disk.  In this case, it's maybe useful to decrease the block size
- if you have a lot of such partitions per table per node - this may heavily increase the size of the bloom filter, because each partition has a separate entry in it.   I saw some customers that had tens of gigabytes of memory allocated for bloom filter only because of the skinny partitions

so it's really depends on the amount of data, access patterns, etc. It could be good or bad, depends on that factors.

If you have date available, and want to use it as part partition key - that may also not advisable because if you're writing and reading a lot of data on that day, then only some nodes will handle that load - this is so-called "hot partitions".

You may implement so-called bucketing, when you infer partition key from the data.  But this will depend on the data available.  For example, if you have date + transaction ID as a string, you may create partition key as date + 1st character of that string - in this case you'll have N partition keys per day, that are distributed between nodes, eliminating the hot partition problem.

See the [corresponding best practices doc from DataStax](https://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/dataModel.html#Checktablestructure) about that topic.

Comment: Thank you @Alex Ott for all the feedback provided, it has been very helpful, and the link provided also. I will analyse more my use case to decide whether to use or not skinny row approach or if it is better to compliment the partition key with another field taking in consideration avoiding the hot partition issue you mentioned,

Answer (score 2):

Let me not get into the different types of keys, but let me mention and shortly explain the two keys you use in your question.

**PRIMARY KEY**

A row MUST have a unique primary key (which identifies the row as what it is regarding equality). The primary key can be a collection of columns (as in your second example with `(the_date), transaction_id`) or just a single column (as in your first example with `transaction_id`). Nevertheless, as mentioned the important part is that for a row the primary key must be unique to identify the row.

**PARTITION KEY**

The partition key is actually determined based on the primary key. You can have composite partition key (you used the syntax for that in your second example, to enforce the `(the_date)` to be the partition key, this is actually not necessary since it would be by default the first column of the primary key).

Cassandra uses the hashed value of the (combined) partition key(s') values to determine on which node(s) the data is stored (or retrieved from when requesting data).

So the answer to your question is, it's totally ok to use the `transaction_id` as primary and partition key. And that is not bad practice, it's more or less pretty common practice if you have a unique identifier in your data which can be stored in one row and fulfills your needs regarding requests.

More Infos:

- [Hashing Explained: Consistent hashing](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.0/cassandra/architecture/archDataDistributeHashing.html)
- [Defining a basic primary key](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/cql/cql/cql_using/useSimplePrimaryKeyConcept.html)
- [Defining a multi-column partition key](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/cql/cql/cql_using/useCompositePartitionKeyConcept.html)

Comment: Thank you @Philipp for elaborating on your response. I understand that given that the primary key consists of one column only, in this case `transaction_id`, this unique field is the primary and partition key also, so each partition in this table would consist of one row only, and my main concern was if this is a perfomance penalty somehow for Cassandra and/or the hosting OS maybe for the handling of multiple files or something

Comment: No there is no penalty in this case (as mentioned in the answer). Again, this is common practice and the Cassandra system.